# How to prevent org-mode from exporting external links

Tags: org-mode, org-export

In my org document, I have some urls that I would like to see exported plain-text, not as links. For example, if I have this in my org document,

```
http://www.pharo.org
```

exporting to HTML will result in this

```html
<a href="http://www.pharo.org/">http://www.pharo.org/</a>
```

but I would like

```
http://www.pharo.org
```

Org automatically recognizes external links even without using the link syntax:

> Org also finds external links in the normal text and activates them as links.

Answer (score 1):

Place the hyperlink in `=` tags to denote `org-code verbatim`.

Org-mode text like this:

```
=http://www.pharo.org=
```

will get exported to HTML that looks like this:

```
<p>
<code>http://www.pharo.org</code> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ORG Manual (12.9.5 Quoting HTML tags):

```
@@html:<span>@@your text@@html:</span>@@
```

is exported as:

```
your text
```

In the case of this question:

```
@@html:<span>@@http://www.pharo.org@@html:</span>@@
```

is exported as:

```
http://www.pharo.org
```

Instead of <span> and </span>, you can use <b> and </b> (ie bold) etc.
( Threre are other ways in that document.)